# I don't know how to design the function to work with the dynamic array

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

So I'm supposed to write some functions in class called ArrayList. I simply don't know where to start or how to manage with the dynamic array. The protected members of the class are:

```
protected:

int *m_list; ///< Pointer to dynamic array.

std::size_t m_capacity; ///< Physical size of dynamic array.

std::size_t m_size; ///< Number of array elements in use.


    /// @brief Appends the given element @p value to the end of the container.
    /// The new element is initialized as a copy of @p value.
    /// If size() == capacity(), the container's size is increased to hold
    /// an additional 16 elements. If the new size() is greater than
    /// capacity(), then all references are invalidated.
    /// @param value The value of the element to append.

    void push_back(const int& value);




    /// @brief Remove unused capacity. All iterators, including the past the
    /// end iterator, and all references to the elements are invalidated.

    void shrink_to_fit();

void ArrayList::shrink_to_fit()
{

}

void ArrayList::push_back(const int& value)
{

}
```

Comment: It looks like your task is to create a [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Take a look at that to get some ideas.

Comment: Naming is important in programming. So you should decide if you want to implement an dynamic array alias vector or a list. ArrayList sounds like a list of arrays...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `shrink_to_fit` you need to resize the dynamic allocated memory and in `push_back` you sometimes need to increase the allocated memory.

So one important piece of code you will need is a resize function, which will do the following:

1. determine the new capacity needed. In `shrink_to_fit` the new capacity is obviously `size`. If you need to resize in `push_back` you may want to increase the capacity not just by 1 to reduce the number of times you have to resize.
2. allocate memory of the required capacity using `new`. For example `auto temp = new int[newCapacity];`
3. Copy all existing items from `m_list` to `temp` using a loop or `memcpy`.
4. delte the old memory using `delete[] m_list;`
5. adjust local variables: `capacity = newCapacity` and `m_list = temp`.

That's the hardest part of handling dynamic memory and I hope it will help you get started.

Answer (score -1):

You will need dynamic memory allocation using `new/delete` or `malloc/free` to handle those methods. Start with allocating memory for 16 integers by appending them to the `m_list` as a linked list.

Comment: This is obviously not a linked list at all but more alike a vector.

Comment: Good comment but not an answer I believe!

Comment: Thanks for the comments!